# Use string as referance for label

Tags: objective-c, string, label

Im having some problem and wondering if anyone could help.

I have a program with several labels declared as day1 day2 day3 day4 day5 day6 day7

```
for(int i=1; i < 8; i++){
NSString *pickerviewtext = @"Apple";
int valuestock;
NSString *cur = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
NSString *stockname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", pickerviewtext, cur];
valuestock = [[savedStock objectForKey:stockname] intValue];
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"day%d", i];
```

The string "key" is the name of the labels and I was wondering if its possible to change the label with the same name as the string to the variable "valuestock", like key.text = but that doesn't work.

Comment: Are you saying that you have a string that has the same name as some UILabel property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

preparation:

```
int numLabels = 8;

NSMutableDictionary  *m_labelMap = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity: numLabels]; 
// m_labelMap should probably be a member of some class

// add each label to m_labelMap:
[m_labelMap setObject: day1 forKey: @"day1"];
[m_labelMap setObject: day2 forKey: @"day2"];
...
```

append behind your code:

```
// --- searching for an entry ---
UILabel *label = [m_labelMap objectForKey: key];
[label setText: valuestock];
```